# Exporting full UTM coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinates, export, utm

I want to export my point layer as CSV with the point coordinates as `"xy"`, QGIS does the job quite well. One problem arises though, and that is that the Easting UTM coordinate is lacking the first two numbers (defining the UTM zone)

So for example, I m working in UTM zone 32(N), the output coordinates look like:

```
x         | y
538790.26 | 5289086.88
```

I need the leading `"32"` here (`"x"`), e.g. `32538790.26`, which is unfortunately missing. Is there a way to export the full UTM coordinates to the .csv column?

Comment: Whenever I receive coordinates including the leading UTM-zone I would like to hug whoever produced this data. Until they turn blue. Because working with such data is a pain in the arse. Why don't you simply put the UTM-zone in the file name?

Comment: our surveying crews need the full UTM coords, the proprietary software they run on their tablets for cadastre measurements etc. requires it. Was not my idea, nor can i change the software they are using.

Comment: If you treat the coordinates like numbers, you simply could add 32 million, either in QGIS or using Excel.

Comment: You might be able to define a custom CRS with the offset, as described here, but there's some warning about it not working with UTM... https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21827/can-we-use-proj-to-offset-coordinates

Comment: EPSG:4647 is ETRS89 / UTM 32N with easting-northing axis ordering that has 32.5 million for the false easting. EPSG:5652 is the same with northing-easting axis ordering. If you look it up at http://www.epsg-registry.org, ignore the description of the extent for Europe. It says 0 to 6E, but should be 6E to 12E. I've let EPSG's chairman know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following Erik's answer solved the problem, simply adding 32 million did the job.
Thank you!

Comment: Geodetically speaking you are exporting to a different coordinate reference system with a false easting of 32 500 000 m instead of 500 000 m,  see question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95642/which-utm-zone-32n-with-prefix-should-i-use-in-rhineland-palatinate-germany for working in a different zone